# rsync to windows share with illegal filename

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to rsync some files from a linux server to a windows share as follows:

```
mount.cifs //X.X.X.X/share /mnt/share -o user=administrator
rsync -avz /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/ /mnt/share/pbx-a/var/spool/asterisk/monitor
```

The problem i'm having is the filenames contain colons, like this:

a01/2015/06/13/11:57:20_outgoing_0XXXXXXXXX7:0XXXXXXXX4.wav

Obviously that filename isn't valid on a Windows share, so it's not copying.

Is there any way rsync can modify the filename somehow, i.e. replace : with - for example?

If not is there another way around this?

I'm unable to control the format of the filenames unfortunately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is solvable, but it will require a basic renaming of the files to change the `':'` to something line an `'_'`. The process is basically copy the files to be transferred to a temporary directory. Rename all files in the temporary directory using 'tr' (or if using bash you can use the builtin **substring replacement**). Once the files are renamed, then `rsync` the newly renamed files to your windows share and remove the temporary directory (that will be handled by `trap` below, but a specific `rm` would work as well)

Putting the pieces together in a short script would look something like the following (the substring replacement is commented out below in favor of `tr`):

```
#!/bin/sh

## script adding file renaming prior to transfer for:
# mount.cifs //X.X.X.X/share /mnt/share -o user=administrator
# rsync -avz /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/ /mnt/share/pbx-a/var/spool/asterisk/monitor

## source dest and temp directories
srcdir=/var/spool/asterisk/monitor
dstdir=/mnt/share/pbx-a/var/spool/asterisk/monitor
wintmp=/tmp/wintmp

[ -d "$wintmp" -a -d "$srcdir" ] || {       ## validate tmpdir & srcdir
    printf "error: srcdir or wintmp not available.\n"
    exit 1
}

trap 'rm -r "$wintmp"' SIGTERM SIGINT EXIT  ## remove wintmp on term or exit

cp -a "${srcdir}"/* "$wintmp" ||  {         ## copy to tmpdir
    printf "error: copy to wintmp failed\n"
    exit 1
}

## rename each file in temp replacing ':' with '_' using 'tr'
while read -r fname; do

    newname=$(cat "$fname" | tr ':' '_') ## replace ':' with '_' using 'tr'
    # newname=${fname//:/_}   ## replace ':' with '_' using substring replacement
    mv "$wintmp/$fname" "$wintmp/$newname"
    [ -f "$wintmp/$newname" ] || {
        printf "warning: newname '%s' not created/found.\n" "$newname"
    }

done < <(find "$wintmp" -type f -printf "%f\n")

rsync -avz "${wintmp}/" "$dstdir"   ## rsync new filenames to win share

## wintmp automatically removed by trap on exit.

exit 0
```

There are many ways to accomplish this. This is one approach. Let me know if you have any questions. If you are running bash, then comment out the line containing `tr` and uncomment the line below using substring replacement (e.g. `newname=${fname//:/_}`). Don't forget to change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I run it though I get: move.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found. Same on line 6 and 12

Comment: That means you have **DOS carriage returns** in your file (that's a no no).  It looks like you copied the file to some editor on windows and then moved it to linux. You can use the utility `dos2unix` to fix the file. Or if you are working on windows, you need to use an editor that doesn't put DOS line ends in your program (like [**Notepad++**](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) that can be configured to use unix line ends). That's my best guess of what your `\r` issue is. (`\r` is the ANSI escape for **carriage return**) (As you can see there is **Nothing** at `line 2` of the script)